# What is used to open file extension .bp2?

Tags: file-io

The full name is filename.tp2.bp2.  I can't seem to find any good info for either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Searching google for `.bp2` and the first result was this

http://www.allfileextensions.net/site/extension/how-do-i-open-a-bp2.html

AutoCad 2013 opens it

Comment: Yes, I agree, but its a Tax Return file, and I'm struggling to find the connection of the two.

Comment: Who gave you the file?

Comment: A family member asked me if I could open it as they could not.

Comment: Ok. I guess you just want the information within the file? Have you tried opening it in notepad?

Comment: Yes, I tried notepad, and sublimeText2, but both did not work.

Comment: Are you completely sure it's a tax return file? If you had AutoCad you could try that ... but I assume you don't! Where did your family member get the file from?

Comment: Oh well, thanks for your help anyway.  I realize it was not a great question, but thanks for your time.